# Drake's equivalent to Simulink's "sources/from workspace"

Tags: python, drake

I'm looking to run a simulation in Drake using `Simulator` and `Simulator.AdvanceTo(T)` after I connect all the blocks of the plant and controller.

I want to add noise by having an array input source that is changing every discrete time step just like the source/from workspace block in Simulink.

I found `RandomSource` which works but I cannot control the sequence. I'd like to be able to have some numpy array `data` of size [n,K] where every time step k \in [0,K] the array `data[:,k]` is fed to the simulator (or whatever interface it has).

As I understand, `ConstantVectorSource` is not the way to go here but I could not find a suitable input or an example. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found this that does what I wish:

```py
pydrake.systems.primitives.TrajectorySource
```

that accepts this as input:

```py
PiecewisePolynomial.ZeroOrderHold(ts, noise_input)
```

Comment: See also the `pydrake.systems.primitives.TrajectorySource` in case that helps.

Comment: Oh yes, definitely, I should've brought that up together because that is the actual block. I'll edit my answer. Thanks!